# nodejs connect to mongodb failed using connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(
  'mongodb://testUser:test@127.0.0.1:27017/testDB',
  {
    db: {
      w: 1,
      native_parser: false,
    },
    server: {
      poolSize: 5,
      socketOptions: { connectionTimeoutMS: 500 },
      auto_reconnect: true,
    },
    replSet: {},
    mongos: {},
  },
  function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Connection Failed Via Connection String.');
    } else {
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://testUser:test@127.0.0.1:27017/testDB", {
    db: { w: 1, native_parser: false },
    server: {
        poolSize: 5,
        socketOptions: { connectionTimeoutMS: 500 },
        auto_reconnect: true
    },
    replSet: {},
    mongos: {}
}, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Connection Failed Via Connection String.");
    } else {
});

Comment: Hi Andrew, The comment can be placed in the original question by using "Edit". Could you also expand on the issue you are having? Describe in the edit what you are attempting to do and any error messages you receive.

Comment: PS C:\Users\trand\MEAN\mongo> node db_connect_string.js
Connection Failed Via Connection String.
PS C:\Users\trand\MEAN\mongo>

Comment: You should print the actual error message, not a static text "Connection Failed Via Connection String.", i.e. `console.log(err.errmsg)` or `console.log(err.message)`

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: i see, so i have take out the options in MongoClient.connect and it can connect now.

Comment: MongoClient.connect("mongodb://testUser:test@127.0.0.1:27017/testDB", 
function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Connection Failed Via Connection String.");
        console.log(err.errmsg);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected Via Connection String ...");
        db.logout(function(err, result) {
    }
});

Comment: PS C:\Users\trand\mean\mongo> node db_connect_string2.js
Connected Via Connection String ...
C:\Users\trand\mean\mongo\db_connect_string2.js:12
        db.logout(function(err, result) {
           ^

TypeError: db.logout is not a function
    at C:\Users\trand\mean\mongo\db_connect_string2.js:12:12
.....

Comment: something wrong with db.logout ??